# Retrieve Last Document ID from Firestore Swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

Hi guys just a simple question with the new Firestore ...

How can you retrieve the last autogenerated document ID from the Firestore database.

[ID examples here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pirF6.png)

Comment: You need insert a timestamp fied for document when added and when get you need order by documentDate with order descending

Comment: So I made something like that `let queryLastDocument = Firestore.firestore().collection("sondages").order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true) print(queryLastDocument)` but now I can't figured how to use only my last document ... https://prnt.sc/gv6o7w

Comment: use limitToFirst(1) if you want get latest document by date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get save your reference in a variable and use it inside your completion block.
From the docs:

```
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("cities").addDocument(data: [
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "country": "Japan"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

The ref!.documentID will do the trick!

If you are talking about getting it in a moment other than the time it's saved, I would recommend to store the last one in a single document in another collection everytime you save a new document.